# How can I access jupyter lab from my home folder in a GCloud Deep Learning VM instance?

Tags: jupyter-lab, google-dl-platform

I have created a deep learning VM instance following the steps on https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/quickstart-cli

Now, I would like to access and run my ipynb notebooks in my home folder.
I followed the steps on https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/jupyter

But, when I tried to visit http://localhost:8080 in my local browser, I got an error saying- This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.

When I tried to access JupyterLab from the preview button in Cloud Shell, I could no longer access my home folder. The only folders visible were "src" and "tutorials".

Could you kindly tell me how I can view and execute the ipynb files stored in my home folder on the VM instance using a Jupyter interface?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 problems here:

1. problem with the connection to the instance (and subsequently problem to reach Jupyter on localhost:8080) and
2. problem with reaching the home folder

Let's address both of them. In order to connect to the instance you need to run the following command:

```
export INSTANCE_NAME=...
gcloud compute ssh $INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

Have you tried it? What was the output?

The second one is the home folder. When you SSH-ing to the instance by default gcloud using your username. However, Jupyter is running under user `jupyter`. In order to SSH under user Jupyter you need to modify gcloud command to look like this:

```
export INSTANCE_NAME=...
gcloud compute ssh jupyter@$INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

You can read more about different way to connect to the DL instance [here](https://blog.kovalevskyi.com/deep-learning-images-for-google-cloud-engine-the-definitive-guide-bc74f5fb02bc).

Comment: Come across this answer, so that means we have to ssh to the user jupyter to use jupyterlab, right? That is a little frustrating.